# Android label with self-updating time (hour and minute)

Tags: android

I want to display the current time (hour:minute) in a label on my app's screen.

Is it possible to have it auto-update as time changes?
   What I mean is, when the minute (and/or the hour) change(s), I want the text/label to autochange it's value, without me having to always check the current time and update it.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Like if there's a special "time" object from the Android API that displays it continuously?

Thanks.

EDIT: If what I want is not possible, can you suggest me a well-designed option of doing it manually?

Comment: You must to use threads to update your label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if this is possible? Like if there's a special "time"
>   object from the Android API that displays it continuously?

There isn't something built in, like others said you would use a `Handler` and update the time yourself. See below a small example:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private TextView mText;// the TextView
private int mHour, mMinute; // variables holding the hour and minute
private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mMinute += 1;
        // just some checks to keep everything in order
        if (mMinute >= 60) {
            mMinute = 0;
            mHour += 1;
        }
        if (mHour >= 24) {
            mHour = 0; 
        }
        // or call your method
        mText.setText(mHour + ":" + mMinute);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // whenever the activity is built or resumed update the time and start posting updates
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mText.setText(mHour + ":" + mMinute);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdate, 60000); // 60000 a minute
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdate);// we need to remove our updates if the activity isn't focused(or even destroyed) or we could get in trouble
    }
```

Instead of the `setText()` part in the `Runnable` you can call your method.

Answer (score 1):

Use Luksprog idea, I create a text view which is self updated Clock Text view.

```
   import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimerTextView extends TextView {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int mHour, mMinute, mSecond;// variables holding the hour and minute
    private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSecond += 1;
            // just some checks to keep everything in order
            if (mSecond >= 60) {
                mSecond = 0;
                mMinute+=1;

            }
            if (mMinute >= 60) {
                mMinute = 0;
                mHour += 1;
            }
            if (mHour >= 24) {
                mHour = 0;
            }
            // or call your method
            setText(mHour + ":" + mMinute+":"+mSecond);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };



    public TimerTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) { 
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdate);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
         setText(mHour + ":" + mMinute+":"+mSecond);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdate, 1000); // 60000 a minute


    }

    public TimerTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TimerTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

}
```

Just drop this custom Textview in your layout XML. It will work automatically

Answer (score 0):

No, although someone's probably written a view that does it, it isn't very hard.  I would simply use a handler and post a delayed message to it that goes off after 1 minute.  When the handler processes the message, have it update the label.  Then have it send itself another message, delayed by another minute.  This way you'll be called once per minute as long as you're in the foreground and update your text view.

Comment: Can you post me the exact code that I should place in `onCreate`?

Consider that I already have a `private final void updateTimeInLabel()` function that does the thing, can you show me the code to call this function every, let's say, 5 seconds?

Also, how to make the loop calls stop once the activity is destroyed (because the activity is part of a larger app and I need the time displayed only for this activity)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler and countDownTimer for this thing if you want to go for manual implementation.
Handler will update the textviews and CountDownTimer will calculate the time on particular frequency basis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . . .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    TextView t;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private int mHour, mMinute,mSecond; // variables holding the hour and minute

    String min,hr,sec;

    private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
             mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
             mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

               min = "" +mMinute;
          hr = "" +mHour;
          sec = "" +mSecond;
         if(min.length()==1 ){

             min = "0"+mMinute;

         }if(hr.length()==1){

             hr = "0" +mHour;

         }if(sec.length()==1){
             sec = "0" +mSecond;

         }
             t.setText(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);     

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        }

      @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        t.setText(mHour + ":" + mMinute + ":" + mSecond);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdate, 1000);
    }

      @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdate);
    }


    }
```