# How can I use if/while statements in Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk

I am very new to Android SDK so that question may be very simple.

I try to make am app that shows the current time. I know how to get the current time but i somehow need to update the time. So i try putting a while/if statement that updates the time outside onCreate() and inside main Activity class but 4 errors pop up saying "unexpected end of Decleration.

I cant really find a way to solve this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using....

Comment: You can't have if/while statements outside of function calls (like onCreate). Besides that, there are a ton of clock tutorials for android out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android label with self-updating time (hour and minute)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502492/android-label-with-self-updating-time-hour-and-minute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the idea that a longer example will be more useful for you.

Make a layout for the application, call the file activity_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.timedemo.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Make a file called MainActivity.java, make it extends Activity (or something else that extends Activity)

Init your layout in the onCreate method.

Use a handler to run code at a delayed time, instead of halting the thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Handler can be used to send Runnables (code to run) to a specific Thread.
//In this case the UI-thread.
Handler handler = new Handler();
//TextView variable defined in Class-scope.
TextView myTextClock;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Load the layout from activity_main.xml into this Activity.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Find the textclock that is mentioned in the activity_main.xml
    //Use the ID to find the right View.
    //As you can see in the xml-file, the id is 'textClock'.
    //Looks like this in the XML --> <TextView android:id="@+id/textClock" />
    myTextClock = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textClock);

    //Tell the Handler to execute this code at an interval.
    handler.postDelayed(codeToRun, 1000);
}

//The runnable contains the code that will be run every second.
Runnable codeToRun = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateTime();
    }
};

public void updateTime(){
    //Code to update the Clock on the UI-thread
    //see: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
    DateFormat sdf = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    myTextClock.setText(sdf.format(new Date()));

    //Make sure it runs the next time too.
    handler.postDelayed(codeToRun, 1000);
} 
}
```

Hope this helps you get on the right path.

Comment: Yep... After days of killing myself trying to find a solution, that works :)) Thank you

Comment: No problem,  nobody is born as an expert ;-) keep making apps !

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) class instead of a `while` loop. There is an example in this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-analogclock-and-digitalclock-example/) on how to create a clock app. It can be useful as a starting point.

```
class ClockTask implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
     updateClock();
  } 
}

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor se = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
se.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ClockTask(), 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```

Comment: That should be the method name where you update the UI.

Comment: Now 15 errors occur. The first is "unknown entity 'ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor'" and the others are "unexpected and of decleration"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you plan to make this, but keep in mind that you do not stall the Main Thread. So avoid a construction like this:

```
while(true){ Thread.sleep(1000); updateTime(); }
```

A better approach would to use Handler, for example:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      updateTime();
  }
}, 1000);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() pops up: expected MainActivity. UpdateTime(); pops: "Expected MainActivity".